# Count number of times two pairs of columns match (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel

I have a five column spreadsheet (A-E), with the following information:

```
       User  | Report   |  COUNT   |   User  | Report
       A     |    1     |          |    A    |    1 
       B     |    2     |          |    A    |    1
       B     |    3     |          |    A    |    2
       B     |    4     |          |    B    |    1
       C     |    2     |          |    B    |    3
       C     |    5     |          |    C    |    24
       D     |    56    |          |    D    |    56



There are ~650 rows for Columns A and B
There are ~12,000 rows for Columns D and E
```

For Columns A and B, there is a unique report to every user.

In Columns D and E, it gives every report ran by every user.

The goal is to input the count result from above into this table:

```
        User | Report   | Rpt.Loc  |   Count  |   Dept. 
       A     |    1     |    aaa   |          |     
       A     |    2     |    bbb   |          |    
       B     |    1     |    ccc   |          |    
       B     |    3     |    ddd   |          |    
       C     |    2     |    bbb   |          |    
       C     |    5     |    eee   |          |    
       D     |    1     |    aaa   |          |    

    User A has ran Report "1" X amount of times, where X will go into Cell D1.
    User A has ran Report "2" Y amount of times, where Y will go into Cell D2.
    User A has ran Report "3" Z amount of times, where Z will go into Cell D3.
```

Comment: I.e. we take each row one by one and check if in that particular row col.A = col.C AND col.B = col.D and then we count the total rows that match this criteria? Right?

Comment: Just to understand, in your example, would the **only** time you got a non-zero value in column E be in the first row (since all other rows don't have A&B matching C&D)? OR would row 2, for example, be true too since there the C&D match A&B from row 1? ... Please re-clarify your question...

Comment: Deleting and rephrasing the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - Meaning you want, for every row, to count the number of times you have whatever is in columns A & B **of that row** appears in columns D & E of your entire worksheet, the formula you would put in cell `C1` would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($D$1:$D$1000,A1,$E$1:$E$1000,B1)
```

And then copy it down for the entire column (Of course, change the final row number from `$1000` to the correct row number for you).

Basically, you're saying: *Count the number of times Column D has the value in this row's A column AND Column E has the value in this row's B column*.

Hope that answers your question and does the trick!!